# Apdu para SmartCard protocolo T1

Tags: c#, smartcard

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion para SmartCard y cuando trabajo con el protocolo T0 la aplicacion corre perfecto pero para T1 la funcion `SCardTransmit` me devuelve:

> ERROR PARAMETROS INVALIDOS

Mi pregunta es ¿el vector tiene el mismo formato para ambos protocolos o cambia el formato del vector?

```
   public void Trasmision()
    {
        Byte[] vectorSend = { 0x00, 0xa4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00 };
        UInt32 inT2 = (UInt32)vectorSend.Length; 
        vectorIn = new Byte[254];
        UInt32 inT = (UInt32)vectorIn.Length;
        IntPtr PT1 =GetPciT0() ;
        this.rTransmit = SCardTransmit(this.hContext, GetPciT0(), vectorSend, inT2, request, vectorIn, inT); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Estoy analizando esta implementacion

[Problems using SCardTransmit from winScard.dll reading a tag 4B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635447/problems-using-scardtransmit-from-winscard-dll-reading-a-tag-4b)

y puedo observar que cambia como define el segundo parametro

Alli veo que usas `GetProcAddress()` con `g_rgSCardT1Pci`, mientras que en tu codigo sigues usando `GetPciT0()` cuandoe sto deberia cambiar

[scardtransmit (winscard)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winscard.scardtransmit)

---

Aqui

[Smartcard communication with protocol t1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679507/smartcard-communication-with-protocol-t1)

se plantea el mismo problema de `invalid parameters`, aunque no estoy seguro de entender la respuesta

Tambien analiza

[A Smart Card Framework for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET)

Comment: Hola  Leandro...Creo que diste en el problema con esta observacion g_rgSCardT1Pci ...pruebo y te comento